# How to make Jquery expand a div on a certain area of your page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just Need Height to expand or collapse based on the amount of information coming from this outsource data. 
Here is my Html code.

```
  <div style="width: 775px; position: relative; left: 15px; top: -745px; height: 250px; border: #CCC; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></div>

  <div style="width: 760px; position: relative; height: 17px; background-color: #Db0000; layer-background-color: #Db0000; border: 1px none #000000; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 16px; padding-top: 4px;"> Promero<span style="font-weight: bold">NEWS</span></div>
<div style="width: 776px; position: relative; height: 2.5px; background-color: #Db0000; layer-background-color: #Db0000; top: 2px;"></div>

<div style="position: relative; width: 775px;">
  <p id="p1" style="color: #E23030; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; font-family: arial, 'Trebuchet MS';">News Release</p>
  <p>July 16, 2012 -<em id="em"><a href="#">Salesforce CRM users connect to Promero's hosted call center software, Oracle Contact Center Anywhere</a></em>
  <p id="p2">March 6, 2012 -<em id="em"><a href="#">Promero offers complete Call Center Solution-Workforce Management-Complex IVR Scripting-CRM</a></em>
  <p>March 1, 2012 -<em id="em"><a href="#">Promero offers Oracle #1 Call Center Software only $59 per User </a></em>
  <p>February 24, 2012 -<em id="em"><a href="#">Promero announces Complex IVR Solution for Oracle CRM</a></em>
  <p>January 15, 2012 - <em id="em"><a href="#">Promero offers customized Dashboards for Oracle Contact Center Anywhere</a></em>
  <p>December 14, 2011 - <em id="em"><a href="#">Promero adds RiverStar CE Suite to Oracle Call Center Cloud Offering</a></em> 
</div>
```

`

Comment: The page needs to expand or collapse based on the amount of information coming from this outsource program.

Answer (score 1):

i dont undrestanding your question but i think you want load news in part of page with jquery
for handeling this issue you can use this code

```
$("#YourElementWillLoadingNewsHere").load("YourUrl from ROOT");
```

this code use for loading jquery into one element,I hope would help u

Answer (score 1):

for this issue u should use this css code

```
#x{
   min-height:50px;
   height:auto;
}
```

this style code cause div height fitting by page news
min-height size is example and you fit this by your data
best regards